# Linq to SQL :How to work with already existing Business objects(Handwritten)

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I was trying to implement a LINQ 2 SQL implementation to one of my page to load the data to a datagrid.The below is the code

```
using (NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
  var customers =from c in context.Customers  select c;   // Line 1
  gridViewCustomers.DataSource = customers;
  gridViewCustomers.DataBind();
}
```

I put a break point in the Line 1 to examine what type is being loaded into customer .But i couldn't see anything there.
What type this customer is of ?

I wanted to put the code to fetch data from Tables in my data access layer which is a seperate classlibrary and would like to call it from UI.What should be the return type of my method in Data access layer ? I already have a another class library which holds buisness objects/entities (Ex: Student).I was using this with Normal ADO.NET stuff before using the LINQ 2SQL stuff.How can i make it work altogether .Kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LinqDataSource` or `ObjectDataSource` to bind the Linq query to the GridView.

See [here](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/gridview-objectdatasource-linq-paging-and-sorting) and [here](http://borrell.parivedasolutions.com/2008/01/objectdatasource-linq-paging-sorting.html) for examples.